# Can't connect my server outside my wireless network. server is openERP running on ubuntu 12.04 desktop router is ciso small business router

Tags: ubuntu, forwarding, odoo

I've looked on the internet regarding port forwarding. I've successfully fowarded port 8069 to my server's ip address.
I can access openERP when I'm connected to the network of my office but not when I'm outside my office's network. What am I missing?
my computer's ip address starts with 192... Do I have to first up the router's ip address and then my server's ip address to get to my server from the outside? what should I type in my internet browser? I've looked all day yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your router must be having a static IP (e.g. 198.x.y.z), then you have to set a port forwarding to your openerp machine.

This can be achieved by setting up a Virtual Server inside your router.

For example, your machines' IP is : 192.168.1.9 and your openerp is running on 8069 port on that machine, then your port forwarding should forward any request that come to your to : 198.x.y.z and port 8069 to 192.168.1.9.